# Environment.rb Load Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When running `rails generate` I get the following error:

> `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in`
>   require': no such file to load --
>   /home/rails_application/config/config/environment.rb
>   (LoadError)`

environment.rb is very much alive and well:

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
RailsApplication::Application.initialize!
```

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see it's trying to load `/home/rails_application/config/config/environment.rb`. Two references to `config`.

Are you perhaps running this command from `config`? If so, try moving back to the Rails root.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to where your original project was created with the 'rails new' command and then run the 'bundle exec' if that is what you wanted to run.  For example, if you type 'ls' and the only thing you see is the a document with an '.rb' extension at the end you will not be able to bundle anything because you don't have any dependencies in that directory.